# If a beam of light of medium proportion shot into space from one side of a planet (lets say Romania), would it be visible to someone in the US?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction

Because the earth is round I feel that it would not be visible to people on the other side of a planet. If not, then how far away from the source would you have to be before it wasn't visible?
The proportion of the beam is about the radius of a car and brightness being people can stare at it without being blinded.

Comment: Define "gigantic proportion" - you mean bright (as in lumens)? Or *wide* (is it one ray of light or 10 solid meters of light)? Or.... ?

Comment: Bright enough that people could stare at it and a radius about the length of a typical car!

Comment: Visibility is entirly dependable of obstructions (in pollution, amount of light etc) remeber that to "see" light you need something it can bounce off. And if there is such thing in air it also limit visibility.

Answer (score 4):

In order to see a beam of light pointing up into the sky, it has to be [scattered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scattering)., and it has to be bright enough that the scattered light is visible. (You could bounce it off other things like aircraft, balloons or satellites, but it wouldn't obviously be a beam then, so I won't consider those solutions)

For a very quick and simple solution, you might consider the highest things that will scatter a decent amount of light to be [cirrostratus clouds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirrostratus_cloud) ([higher clouds exist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_mesospheric_clouds), but they are polar phenomena rather than things that can be found anywhere in the world, so I'll ignore them).

Lazily ignoring the effects of [atmospheric diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon#Effect_of_atmospheric_refraction), the furthest distance $d$ that you can see an object that is $h_c$ metres high from an observation point $h_o$ metres above sea level is given by $d \approx 3.57 (\sqrt{h_c} + \sqrt{h_o})$. Cirrostratus clouds can be found up to 13000m, so for a 2m tall person at sea level you'd be able to see them being illuminated by the beam of light from at most 412km away. This will be reduced by things like obstacles (obviously) and by anything that attenuates light such as [atmospheric haze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haze). The presence of bright sunlight might also make the scattered light invisible to the naked eye, so this probably works best at night.

If you want to allow for refraction, then the maths gets harder but there is an adequate approximation that just changes the 3.57 to 3.86, so the viewing distance in the previous example becomes at most ~446km. Observers on a mountain or in an aircraft could of course view this from much, much further away, but you can do that maths yourself for the viewpoints of your choice.

I'm not sure how bright the source would have to be in order for the scattering to be visible at this distance, but the answer is probably Quite Bright.

Now, if you were using a laser it could be intense enough to be scattered by air without needing the presence of clouds to be visible. I am not, however, sure of how tenuous the atmosphere can get before the scattering of a suitable laser becomes invisible. You may find that it exceeds the altitude of the cirrostratus clouds, and so the beam would be visible from much further away, but I can't be sure.

---

With regards to your specific question, visible from the US, lets imagine that the light is visible from far away, scattered from clouds at 20000m, and the observer is standing on the summit of [Denali](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denali) at 6194m, and they're the same 2m tall as before. That gives a maximum sight range, including the refraction approximation, of nearly 850km. Even from a U2 spy plane at 21336m, the maximum range is 1110km. Romania is 7753km away from Alaska, so the answer is **no**.

Comment: *"A beam of light pointing up into the sky":* nowhere does the question say that the beam is pointing up. If it were me, I would make the beam parallel to the ground...

Comment: @AlexP if only there were some way for you to write your own answer :-(

Answer (score 0):

One possible way for the beam to be seen from many thousands of miles away would be if it isnot a beam of light but a particle beam of some sort and that every split second a fraction of the particles decay into other particles that emit light.

Thus the mean might leave a trail of light emitting particles behind it so that at any moment a part of the particle beam might be emitting light, a long enough section of the particle beam that it would appear to be a line in outer space, pointing to the direction of the place on Earth it was emitted from.  Thus people might be able to calculate the beam was emitted from Roumania.

Of course enough of the particles would have to decay into light emitting particles each fraction of a second for the light emitted to be bright enough to be seen at a distance of thousands of miles.  And at the same time only a tiny fraction of the total particles in the beam could decay in each split second if the beam was going to extend for thousands of miles above the Earth.

So together those two factors indicate that the particle beam would have to be extremely intense in order for it to be visible for thousands of miles on the surface of the Earth.

Or possibly some process would shoot a column of molecules, or atoms, or subatomic particles of some sort, many thousands of miles high above Roumania.  And then an intensely strong laser beam would be shot up from Roumania along the same path, and some of the laser light would strike particles and be reflected in all directions, enough light for the beam to be visible from thousands of miles away on Earth.

I am not up to calculating how far up the beam would have to be visible from different distances on the surface of the Earth, and I can not calculate what the composition of the beam would have to be.

But I hope that these ideas may be useful suggestions.